# Writing dates to SQL Server data from R

Tags: sql-server, r, r-dbi

I am saving a `data.frame` through odbc to an SQL Server database in a new table. The `data.frame` contains dates in one column.

I am using the following commands:

```
require(odbc)
require(DBI)

MyData <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2017-05-17","2017-05-18"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(), dsn='MyDatabaseSource')

dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = 'dbo.MyTable', value = MyData, overwrite = T)
```

However, this results in the following error message:

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22007: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I can resolve it by changing the column type to `character`, but then the column is stored as `varchar(255)` in the database. How do I store the Date column in the date format in the database and not `varchar`?

Comment: What is the type of that column in the database?

Comment: The table doesn't exists, so dbWriteTable creates the table...

Comment: Don't use language-dependent format yyyy-mm-dd, use yyyymmdd

Comment: @sepupic I can't seem to change the format without changing it the type to `chr`. I have tried `MyData$Date <- as.Date(format(MyData$Date, "%Y%m%d"), format = "%Y%m%d")`, but the format remains `yyyy-mm-dd`. How do I change the format?

Comment: @sepupic Now the command above works. I must have made some mistake. If you write up an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by using the language-independent date format yyyymmdd as suggested by sepupic in the comments. I did this by changing date column to `chr` in the yyyymmdd format and then back to the date format:

```
MyData$Date <- as.Date(format(MyData$Date, "%Y%m%d"), format = "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: For me the problem seemed to be passing a date object - the proposed solution didn't work for me. Instead I had to convert the dates to character strings using `as.character()` before writing to SQL. I could then pass dates in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' without any issues.